# Python: how do I make a recursive function that returns a string of words in reverse order?

Tags: python, recursion, reverse

I'm trying to create a recursive function that accepts a string as a parameter and returns the words in that string in reverse. To clarify, if the string was "Today is Sunday", it's supposed to return "Sunday is Today". Here's what I have so far:

```
def reverse(msg):
    new_msg = msg.split()
    if len(new_msg)==0:
        return new_msg
    else:
        return str(new_msg[-1])+str(reverse(new_msg[0:-1]))
```

But once I use a string as a parameter, the console gives me "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'". What can I do to fix this?

Comment: In `reverse(new_msg[0:-1])`, what's the type of `new_msg`? Is it a string?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that your function is mixing lists with strings. Use the `join` method to convert the list you created with `split` back to a string.

Update your function to:

```py
def reverse(msg):
    new_msg = msg.split()
    if len(new_msg) <= 1:
        return msg
    else:
        return new_msg[-1] + " " + reverse(" ".join(new_msg[0:-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use string indexing, particularly negative indexes, then there's no point to using recursion:

```
def reverse(msg):
    return " ".join(msg.split()[-1::-1])
```

Let's eliminate the indexes and use the `maxsplit` argument to `split()` to keep from doing work that we might otherwise just throw away again with a `join()`:

```
def reverse(message):
    if not message:
        return message

    first, *rest = message.split(maxsplit=1)

    if not rest:
        return first

    return reverse(*rest) + ' ' + first

print(reverse("get your facts first then you can distort them as you please"))
```